# redeclaring array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to port some C code over to C++ and an array declaration (or rather, a series of array declarations) is giving me problems.  The code is organized like this:  first, a global array is declared, like so:

```
static const Foo foos[100];
```

Then, a bunch of other arrays are declared and initialized, all of which reference certain elements of the `foos` array, like so:

```
static const Bar bar1[3] = { .... &foos[3]; .... }
```

Finally, the original array is re-declared and initialized.  The elements of the array make references to the bunch of arrays we just declared (in other words, the structures are mutually recursive):

```
static const Foo foos[100] = { .... &bar1[1]; .... }
```

In C, this works fine.  The first declaration just serves to say "hey, I'm going to need an array of 100 Foo's later on", and then the second declaration actually tells the compiler what data we'd like to populate the array with.  Because the structures I'm dealing with are mutually recursive, this all works out really nicely.

**However**, C++ is giving me real problems with the re-declaration.  I'm not really a C++ programmer, but I believe this all has something to do with C++'s rules on default initialization.

So here's my question:  **how can I capture the above model in C++**?  How can I pre-declare the type and size of an array without actually initializing the contents?

(Don't bother telling me this is bad design -- I'm actually working on a compiler that targets C, so it's irrelevant whether the design of the computer-generated C code is good or bad.  I'd just like to know how to pre-declare arrays of structures in C++.)

Comment: Are you sure it is worth the effort to port your C code to C++? C++ is designed to be compatible with C!

Comment: You *can't* redefine something that is already defined. It seems to me that what you want is to *initialize* `foos` and not "redeclare" it.

Comment: This seems like really bad design. I would suggest re-designing it instead of trying to "port" this somehow.

Comment: @Borgleader Actually I'm working on a C code generator and I'm trying to make the resultant generated code C++-compatible.  The design is computer-generated, and not supposed to be "good".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in C because C has *tentative definitions*, which weren't carried over to C++. For example, this is perfectly legal C code, but illegal C++ code:

```
int a;
int a;
int a;
```

If you want to declare an array (or any other variable) without defining it, use `extern`:

```
extern const Foo foos[100];   // declaration

const Foo foos[100] = ...;    // definition
```

You cannot combine `extern` with `static`, but you can put stuff into an anonymous namespace, which more or less has the same effect. Note that top-level variables are always static; the `static` modifier on a global variable means "limit the visibility of this variable to the current translation unit".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it static, change the declaration of Foo to extern.

```
extern const Foo foos[];

static const Bar bar[] = { ..., &foos[13], ... };
const Foo foos[] = { ..., &bar[1], ... };
```